# logically adding in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to do the following operation. But It likes the histogram operation.

```
maxIndex = 6    
dst  =zeros((1,6))
a    =array([1,2,3,4,7,0,3,4,5,7])
index=array([1,1,1,3,3,4,4,5,5,5])
```

`a`'s length == `index`'s length,

```
for i in (a.size):
    dst[index[i]] = dst[index[i]] + a[i]
```

**How can I do this more pythonic. and more efficiently**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning identical array indices at once in Python/Numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273634/assigning-identical-array-indices-at-once-in-python-numpy)

Comment: The 1D case was just asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514890/array-modified-via-two-others-in-python).

Comment: This question appears to belong on codereview.stackexchange.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you are looking for [`numpy.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

```
dst = numpy.bincount(index, weights=a, minlength=maxIndex)
```

This give me `array([  0.,   6.,   0.,  11.,   3.,  16.])` as the output.  If you don't want to calculate `maxIndex` by hand, you can omit `minlength` parameter from the function call and `numpy` will return an appropriately-sized array for you.

Comment: `minlength` should be set to `maxIndex` to match OP's output.

Comment: @KennyTM I think you're right.  I wasn't sure what `maxIndex` was doing in his question.  What the OP probably really wants is the default behavior, without the `minlength` parameter since that will return an array with a non-zero last element...

Comment: very nice. That's what i want